# Angular-ui: tab contents from separate html file

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this simple tab panel:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
<tabset>
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
  {{tab.content}}
</tab>
</tabset>
</div>
```

and this simple controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function   ($scope) {
$scope.tabs = [
{ title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'/tab1.html' },
{ title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2'}
];
});
```

my problem is that I would like for tab 1 to get its contents from an .html file, not from the static array. Is there a way to achieve this?
If it can be of some use here's my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mFkI7oDIeamqd444wlqr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ng-include is your friend

```
<div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bAqoP9oY5apKAvvPQxOe?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I have put `ng-include="'managetab.html'"` first , it shows

> WARNING: Tried to Load Angular More Than Once

Then i put

```
<div ng-include="'app/views/managetab.html'"></div>
```

works fine ....